# "IF" Function Question

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-workspace, google-sheets-query, worksheet-function

So I have run into an issue...
This maybe simple, but I just can't figure it out.

On a spreadsheet on Google Sheets, I need for a cell to populate a total when a certain cell contains another variable.

So I want the money spent in 2020 row to only pickup the dollar amount in the "Money" column that contains the date 2020 (or 20 for that matter) in the "Date" column.

[image]

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `sumifs`

```
=SUMIFS(E2:E10,A2:A10,">31/12/2019",A2:A10,"<01/01/2021")
```

With `If`

```
=sum(arrayformula(If(year(A2:A10)=$J$2,E2:E10,)))
```

where `A` is the **Date** column, `E` the **Money** column, and `$J$2` is the `2020`

Comment: Thank you so much...this was really bothering me! I have just dipped my foot into this Sheets/Excel stuff.  Thank you once again!